# SQL Server 2008 -- execute queries in parallel

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there an easy way to execute queries in parallel?  I have a query that has something like this:

```
delete from TableA where id = @id
delete from TableB where id = @id
delete from TableC where id = @id
...
```

and I want to do them in parallel.  I can also use C#, though not sure how.

Comment: Note that if those tables have foreign key relationships between them it may not be as performant as you think.

Comment: Ya, all these tables are independent, except for a master table, which I would do last.

Comment: Is it really a perf problem and worth complicating the code with parallel processing to delete some rows by id from three tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is to have separate threads and separate connections but I think you can manage it with multiple connections in a single thread using async callbacks:

```
string[] tables = new string[] { "TableA", "TableB", "TableC" ... };
var runningCommands = new List<SqlCommand>();
foreach(var table in tables)
{
  var conn = new SqlConnection(...);
  conn.Open();
  var cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE id = @id");
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id);
  cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(); 
  runningCommands.Add(cmd);
}
// now wait for all of them to finish executing
foreach(var cmd in runningCommands)
{
  cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery();
  cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Parallelizing doesn't really matter - requests are still performed sequentially in the database.  That's why you'd use transaction logs to restore to a particular point in time.

Comment: thanks, this is probably close to what I want, though also unfortunately, we're in .NET 1.1.. will need to convince them to update

Comment: @OMG Ponies - you don't think it would take advantage of the multiple cores?

Comment: @Timmy: Taking advantage of multi-cores means very little if you can't restore mission critical data.  You can run your queries as you like, but check the transaction logs afterwards & you'll find they aren't at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, it was an honest question, I think most of these tables are cache-type tables where things are calculated and while maybe mission critical, they are reproducible and gets turned over a bit.. not sure about the math, but at least that's the logic

Comment: It may help your case for upgrade that .NET 1.1 hasn't been supported for three years: http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&qid=&alpha=.NET+Framework+1.1&Filter=FilterNO

Comment: @OMGPonies only DB write operations are serialized. A DELETE query is more than that (parse the query, find the right record in DB). You can benefit from that at least.

Comment: Write queries aren't serialized either. Two concurrent queries can both write to different pages in memory. Before they commit successfully they need to wait until their last LSN is written to the logfile. Restoring to a particular point in time just means restoring to those transactions that were committed at that point in time.

Comment: Well unless you have a RAID setup the storage implies a serialization more or less.

Comment: @ssg - The log files are always written to sequentially but that happens independent of the particular user transactions. i.e. they just carry on their work independently and write to [the log cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186259.aspx) which must be flushed at least up to the last LSN for a transaction before that transaction commits.

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks, I'm doing my best, this is just another case =)

Answer (score 2):

```
    List<string> list;
    list.Add("query1");
    list.Add("query2");
    list.AsParallel().ForAll(query => ExecuteQuery(query));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SSIS. Put 3 Execute sql tasks on the control flow. Add a delete statement to each task. When the package executes, they will all get executed at the same time.

You could also create a job for each statement and schedule them all to run at the same time.

Async callback would also work, but the 2 above are easier for someone with a dba skillset to implement and manage.